# Csv import to database form url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm trying to have this url place everything in the csv into my database.

here is the code i have so far

```
require 'open-uri'
namespace populate do
   task reload: :environment do
       Afftable.delete_all
       url = 'something.com/format=csv'
       CSV.open(url).each do |row|
         Afftable.create(name: row[0], address: row[1])
       end
   end
end
```

When i try running this command i get this error

Command: `bundle exec rake populate:reload`

Error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method`populate' for main:Object`

My database has all the headers in the csv file already inside the database. (i've not touched the create yet as i don't really know what im doing with this)

Comment: You have a small syntax error, it should be `namespace :populate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need a colon in front of populate.
`namespace :populate do`

Comment: NameError: uninitialized constant Afftable has now appeared, Suppose its helpful!

Comment: See my new question, Kinda going off on a tangent in this one :)

Comment: Does it gives you the error when it hits the
```   Afftable.delete_all```
 line?

Comment: `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` this is the current error im on now

Comment: Hey Sam, you  may also need to:
``` require 'csv' ``` 
on the top of the file.
Also, for the ENOENT, consider doing a curl to that address fro the command line.